# What is this in my tables

Tags: database

Cleaning up my databases and I found this in my main table  atpp_options  perhaps from a plugin, anyone have any idea what it might be?

Comment: It will be better if you look at the table contents before removing it. It can be your WordPress options table if you have prefixed tables with atpp_ during the install.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely from a plugin, unless you gave your WordPress install a prefix of "atpp_". Assuming you do not have the plugin active, you can safely remove it.

Comment: yeah i figured it out, its from an old translation I removed, guess it didnt uninstall everything... grrrr :) cheers

Answer (score 0):

I would guess at it belonging to a plugin you have installed or used to have installed.

Any plugins that you have had installed or current have installed where its initials would spell ATPP?